# Nightwatchjs: how to solve Error retrieving a new session from the selenium server?

Tags: windows, nightwatch.js

This is my part of my config:

```
"selenium": {
        "start_process": true, // tells nightwatch to start/stop the selenium process
        "server_path": "./selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar",
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": 4444, // standard selenium port
        "cli_args": {
            "webdriver.chrome.driver": "./chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe"
        }
    },

test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "use_ssl": true,
      "credentials": {
        "username": "admin",
        "key": "secret"
      },
```

The test was running fine until I inserted use_ssl. Now I am getting this error:

Error retrieving a new session from the selenium server

Connection refused! Is selenium server started?

```
{ Error: write EPROTO 101057795:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:797:

    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:800:14) code: 'EPROTO', errno: 'EPROTO', syscall: 'write' }
```

I am trying to test a page which requires windows authentication.

Comment: that doesn't sound an ssl issue, are there any other errors on the selenium server side?

Comment: @StratosIon nope no other errors. I also can't find a sample with a firefox profile, do you know any

Comment: What is the last output of the selenium server?

Comment: @StratosIon I just updated the question.

Comment: Could you provide with some more information?
Selenium setup and version, which driver and version

Comment: @StratosIon see above

Comment: Try `access_key` instead of `key`?